# Explain $z(\cos z -1)$ serie expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Look at the following expansion, which should be an expansion from for the coefficients $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$

$$\begin{align} 
z(\cos z -1) &= z \left( 1 - z^2/2!+ z^4/4! - z^6/6! + O\left(|z|^8\right) -1 \right)\\ 
&= z \left(-z^2/2! + O\left(|z|^4\right)\right)\\
&= -z^3/2 + O(|z|^5)
\end{align}$$

Which results in

$$ a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = 0, a_3 = - \dfrac12$$

I'm having problem which understanding the $O$-term. Why is it present at all since, we're just interested in 4 terms anyway and why/how is it changed from $z^8$ to $z^4$ in one step.

Comment: Without the $O$'s you don't have equalities.

Comment: It is present because, except for a few special values of $z$, one has $\cos z - 1 \neq -z^2/2 + z^4/4! - z^6/6!$. Why it was changed from $O(\lvert z\rvert^8)$ to $O(\lvert z\rvert^4)$ is anybody's guess.